# how to select all from one table and one only from another linked with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

database table
1.products,
2.productsImg - productID as foreign key

want to select * from products and one image per product from productsImg using mysql

Comment: You need to post complete table structures for both tables

Comment: Product table 
Field        
| id        
| name       
| rating and ProductImg table Field |id |name |productId foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql:

```
select p.*, pi.name from products p join productsImg pi on pi.productId=p.id group by p.id
```

Here I am assuming "name" field in productsImg table has image name.

Comment: it works but it selects all the images for each products.what i need is one image for each product like selecting all from the products table and limiting one image row using foreign key for each product

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. Edited my answer to change "order by" to "group by"

Comment: what if i want to do smthg like this            "select p.*, pi.imagename from products p where sellerId = $sellerID join productImg pi on pi.productId=p.id group by p.id LIMIT $StartingLimit, $resultPerPage".if show me error

Comment: you can use limit to control the number of records returned